# because I am funny, not good-looking

Tags: ambiguity

a. He likes me because I am funny, not good-looking.
b. He likes me because I am funny, not because I am good-looking.

In which case am I good-looking?
In which case is it possible that I am good-looking? (One can't tell for sure)

Is there any ambiguity in those sentences?

Many thanks

Comment: Tortuously teasing out a misreading from a sentence that virtually nobody would ever misunderstand in a real-world situation is pointless time-wasting unless you're trying to be a comedian. Ambiguous language exists everywhere, but human beings don't even notice it because we have common sense to guide us. Man is not a mindless machine.

Comment: If you're truly funny you should be able to make the decision for yourself.

Comment: @Fumble Fingers - for some reason I was under the impression that "*marked as duplicate-this question already has an answer*" meant that OP's question had not *only* elicited an answer(s), but elicited one that satisfied the OP and had been officially *selected*. Which is not true of the instant case. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **both sentences are ambiguous**. Either one can mean you're good-looking.

- A. "You are good-looking. Maybe that's why he likes you so much."
- B. "He likes me because I am funny, not (because I am) good-looking.

If the verb used in the first clause fits the second, no problem omitting "not because + subject + verb" (e.g. I am funny, I am beautiful) If you use a different verb, you obviously can't omit it, though. (e.g. I am funny, I speak French.)

Answer (score 1):

They are both ambiguous, (b) is just a longer way of saying (a). Both could mean:

> I am not good looking but he likes me because I am funny.

OR:

> I am good looking but that's not why he likes me, he likes me because I
>   am funny.